# WP7 - Textbox Display Error

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, scroll

I'm wondering if this is a default silverlight control error or something i did. Basically i have this textbox inside a scrollviewer which has a auto width so the textbox will scroll depending on how much characters there are. Code:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="111" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,8,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="scroller">
            <TextBox TextWrapping="NoWrap" Background="#BF000000" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="#BF000000" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" FontSize="56" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" Height="141" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" x:Name="Titletxt" InputScope="Chat">
                <TextBox.CaretBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
                </TextBox.CaretBrush>
            </TextBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

The problem is that if the user types an incredibly long title the textbox cuts of so the text stops from one point and i cant see the text its all black but as i type the scroll viewer is automatically scrolling while the user is typing but the text cannot be seeing.

Example : http://puu.sh/5uhmq.png

So what's wrong and how can i fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max size of a control in WP7 is 2048x2048 - the TextBox is probably exceeding this amount when the user types an extremely long title.

I would either not allow the user to type that long of a title, or put a MaxWidth of 2048 on the TextBox and allow it to wrap.